# Trying to close all opened forms in visual basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, unhandled-exception

I want it so when my button is clicked, I exit my application. I tried a simple for loop:

```
Private Sub CloseAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
    For Each Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        Form.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

But after closing all forms besides the form with this button on it, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I believe this is because I close the form executing the code before the loop can go to the next form. If this is the case, how can I make it so my loop finishes once the last form is closed? Can I even do that?

Comment: Do you want to exit the application or you want close all forms except the current form?

Comment: If you close the main/statup form the app will likely end, is that what you want?

Comment: Is this what you need? `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Close all but current form:**

```
My.Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form)() _
              .Except({Me}) _
              .ToList() _
              .ForEach(Sub(form) form.Close())
```

**Close application normally:**

```
Application.Exit()
```

**Force application to exit:**

```
Environment.Exit(1)
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind `Environment.Exit(1)`? As my understanding that is used for console based applications... Also if you don't have the permission flag you will throw a security exception.

Comment: @Codexer [`Environment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating system.

Comment: I know what it does but why doesn't Application.Exit suffice enough?

Comment: @Codexer The difference is between close gently or force to exit (kill). For example, put a message box in closing event of some forms and ask about if you really want to close the form and set `e.Cancel=true` to see the difference.

Comment: @Codexer You are welcome:) Hope you find the answer useful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, just add a validation:

```
        For Each Form In My.Application.OpenForms
            If Form.name <> Me.Name Then
                Form.Close()
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Also make sure to set Shutdown Mode from :`When startup form closes` to `when last form closes`

Comment: In a foreach loop on a generic list you have modified the list (you have added or removed something). That can not be done.

Answer (score 1):

what this does is close all form except "exceptthisform" or the mainform

```
     Dim formNames As New List(Of String)

        For Each currentForm As Form In Application.OpenForms

            If currentForm.Name <> "exceptthisform" Then

                formNames.Add(currentForm.Name)

            End If

        Next

        For Each currentFormName As String In formNames
            Application.OpenForms(currentFormName).Close()

        Next
```